# EditText, Do not allow copy/paste from one to other

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have two edit text defined in layout. Both of them are for email address 
Once user enter in first box, I want to force user to reenter the same email address again without doing any copy paste operation.

Comment: Please don't. Please be advised that typing on a mobile device is fairly annoying, particularly for those of us who are not especially good with touchscreens. Forcing the user to do redundant data entry is not a good plan. Use *one* `EditText` for the email address. Use `android:inputType="textEmailAddress"` to help the user enter it correctly. Use a regular expression to confirm basic validity of the entered address, then either test it (e.g., send a confirmation email to the address) or simply allow the user to fix it later in case of a typo.

Comment: I do believe in UX and its limitation, but if product demands it then I have to implements it. I do like your suggestion but they are not accepted for this project at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Haven't tested this, but I think you could just override the OnLongClick listener (for each of your EditTexts) so that it doesn't display a context menu.  Therefore they wouldn't be able to copy and paste.

```
 OnLongClickListener mOnLongClickListener = new OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        //since nothing is in here, nothing will happen.  

        return true;
    }
};
```

Comment: no problem, I'm glad it worked. Mark it as the correct answer if you don't mind :)

Comment: Just press the checkmark that should be next to the number "1" to the left of my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can set, in textView´s properties (xml file) the next property:

android:longClickable="false".

this will avoid the longclick event in your textView.